# Oracle Return the correct size of column definition not in BYTE

Tags: oracle

Hy guys,
i have a problem,
i have a table with 2 fields

`CREATE TABLE TEST( FIELD1 VARCHAR2(2 CHAR), FIELD2 VARCHAR2(3 CHAR) );`

if i ran this query (Oracle SQL Developer)

```
SELECT DATA_LENGTH FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=TEST;
```

that return, the length of the columns in BYTE, but i would like the correct size that is "2 and 3" not in bytes, my tables as data types are all `varchar2`.

is there a way to get the correct value?

Thx all for the support.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct size"? i.e. what do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: correct size for me is the size of columns definition. I just edited the content I hope it is clea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct size and data length are two different concepts, specially when you have a MULTIBYTE characterset in your database.

When you define a column in Oracle with length varchar2(3 byte) you are instructing Oracle to store 3 bytes maximum. However, if your database uses a multibyte characterset as UTF8, data length and data size are not always the same, and some characters will need far more bytes to be stored.

Let me illustrate the answer with an example:

```
SQL> col parameter for a30
SQL> col value for a30
SQL> select parameter,value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8

SQL> create table check_size ( c1 varchar2(2 byte), c2 varchar2(2 char) );

Table created.

SQL> col column_name for a30
SQL> col data_type for a30
SQL> col data_length for 999999
SQL>  SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
  2            DATA_TYPE,
  3            DATA_LENGTH,
  4            CASE
  5              WHEN CHAR_USED = 'C' THEN
  6                'CHAR'
  7              WHEN CHAR_USED = 'B' THEN
  8                'BYTE'
  9            END AS BYTE_OR_CHAR
 10       FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
 11      WHERE OWNER='TEST'
 12*     AND TABLE_NAME = 'CHECK_SIZE'

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE                      DATA_LENGTH BYTE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------- ----
C1                             VARCHAR2                                 2 BYTE
C2                             VARCHAR2                                 8 CHAR

SQL>  insert into check_size values ( 'aa' , 'aa' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>  insert into check_size values ( 'aä' , 'aa' ) ;
 insert into check_size values ( 'aä' , 'aa' )
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEST"."CHECK_SIZE"."C1" (actual: 7,
maximum: 2)
```

As you can see, the second insert fails, because it actually needs more bytes to store those characters.

```
SQL>  select dump('ää') as content from dual ;

CONTENT
--------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=12: 239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189,239,191,189

SQL>  alter table check_size modify c1 varchar2(12 byte) ;

Table altered

SQL>  insert into check_size values ( 'ää' , 'aa' );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
```

NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, and NCLOB columns are always character-based.

Sessions logged as SYS do not use the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter. They use BYTE length semantics for all created objects unless overridden by the explicit BYTE and CHAR qualifiers in object definitions (SQL DDL statements).

I hope it clarifies better the concepts of data size and data length when columns are defined in table DDL and the relationship with the CHARACTERSET of the database.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know which unit this data size shows then you can use the `CHAR_USED` column (This is the character you used at time of creating the table and due to this character, actual maximum data this column can hold, changes) from `USER_TAB_COLS` as follows:

Let's create the table with the default, `BYTE` and `CHAR` unit:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE (
  2  YOURCOLUMN_CHAR      VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  3  YOURCOLUMN_BYTE      VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  4  YOURCOLUMN_DEFAULT   VARCHAR2(100)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Let's see what is stored in the mentioned view:

```
SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
  2         DATA_TYPE,
  3         DATA_LENGTH,
  4         CASE
  5           WHEN CHAR_USED = 'C' THEN
  6             'CHAR'
  7           WHEN CHAR_USED = 'B' THEN
  8             'BYTE'
  9         END AS BYTE_OR_CHAR
 10    FROM USER_TAB_COLS
 11   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLE';

COLUMN_NAME               DATA_TYPE       DATA_LENGTH BYTE
------------------------- --------------- ----------- ----
YOURCOLUMN_CHAR           VARCHAR2                100 CHAR
YOURCOLUMN_BYTE           VARCHAR2                100 BYTE
YOURCOLUMN_DEFAULT        VARCHAR2                100 BYTE

SQL>
```

Comment: the first now it's not correct data_length is 400 Char